# Error closing postgres connection between each function

Tags: python, postgresql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, psycopg2

I have 2 python functions that handle an event in a lambda function that are essentially the same thing. When checking the logs in AWS I get the following error:

```
{
  "errorMessage": "local variable 'post_connection' referenced before assignment",
  "errorType": "UnboundLocalError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/etl_python/handler.py\", line 11, in handle\n    EtlCall.run_bc(event)\n",
    "  File \"/var/task/etl_python/elt_call.py\", line 153, in run_bc\n    if post_connection:\n"
  ]
}
```

My code looks like this:

```
def run_bo(event):

        
        s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
        idv_endpoint = os.getenv('DB_ENDPOINT')
        idv_database = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
        filename = 'staging/aml_bo'
        bucket = os.getenv('BILLING_ETL')

        if 'resources' in event and "psql_billing" in event['resources'][0]:
                try:
                    config = VaultService()
                    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
                    idv_endpoint = os.getenv('DB_ENDPOINT')
                    idv_database = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
                    filename = 'staging/billing_bo'
                    bucket = os.getenv('BILLING_ETL')
                    idv_username = config.get_postgres_username()
                    idv_password = config.get_postgres_password()

                    post_connection = psycopg2.connect(user = idv_username
                                        , password = idv_password
                                        , host = idv_endpoint
                                        , port = "5432"
                                        , database = idv_database)
        
                    cursor = post_connection.cursor()
                    bo_qry = "SELECT uuid\
                    ,first_name, middle_initial, last_name, date(date_of_birth) 
                    mailing_address,  public.bo"
            #Might need not need the next two lines but this should work.
                    query = """COPY ({}) TO STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '|', QUOTE '"', HEADER TRUE)""".format(bo_qry)
                    file = StringIO()
                    cursor.copy_expert(query, file)
                    s3_resource.Object(bucket, f'{filename}.csv').put(Body=file.getvalue())
                    cursor.close()
                except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
                    print("Error connecting to postgres instance", error)

                finally:
                    if post_connection:
                        cursor.close()
                        post_connection.close()
                        
                #return "SUCCESS"

        else:
            # Unknown notification
            #raise Exception(f'Unexpected event notification: {event}')
            print("Cannot make a solid connection to psql instance. Please check code configuration")

def run_bc(event):


        if 'resources' in event and "psql_billing" in event['resources'][0]:
                try:
                    config = VaultService()
                    s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
                    idv_endpoint = os.getenv('DB_ENDPOINT')
                    idv_database = os.getenv("DB_NAME")
                    filename = 'staging/billing_bc'
                    bucket = os.getenv('BILLING_ETL')
                    idv_username = config.get_postgres_username()
                    idv_password = config.get_postgres_password()

                    post_connection = psycopg2.connect(user = idv_username
                                        , password = idv_password
                                        , host = idv_endpoint
                                        , port = "5432"
                                        , database = idv_database)
        
                    cursor = post_connection.cursor()
                    bc_qry = "select id, uuid, document_type, image_id, 
               document_id\
                    
                    from public.bc"
            #Might need not need the next two lines but this should work.
                    query = """COPY ({}) TO STDIN WITH (FORMAT csv, DELIMITER '|', QUOTE '"', HEADER TRUE)""".format(bc_flowdown_qry)
                    file = StringIO()
                    cursor.copy_expert(query, file)
                    s3_resource.Object(bucket, f'{filename}.csv').put(Body=file.getvalue())
                    cursor.close()
                except(Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
                    print("Error connecting to postgres instance", error)

                finally:
                    if post_connection:
                        cursor.close()
                        post_connection.close()
                        
                #return "SUCCESS"

        else:
            # Unknown notification
            #raise Exception(f'Unexpected event notification: {event}')
            print("Cannot make a solid connection to psql instance. Please check code configuration")
```

I don't understand how my connection is unbound if I am closing the connection and the connection after each function and then reopening it for the next. I close it at the end when the data is dumped to my file and then create a new connection in the next function.

Comment: Could it be that you are getting an error in your `try` block before the line that assigns to `post_connection`?  Try adding a line `post_connection = None` to the top of the `try` block.

Comment: @LukeWoodward you mean above the `try` block correct?

Comment: There are two `try` blocks in your code (sorry, I missed seeing the second one), one in `run_bo` and one in `run_bc`.  Try adding the line I mentioned to both `try` blocks.  Looking closely at the traceback the error is coming out of the second `try` block, i.e. the one in `run_bc`, but it would be worth making the change to both of them.